# Performance gap issue between Task.WaitAll() and execute Task.Wait sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, task

I want to add concurrency to some synchronous code, and found a performance issue in the process, which difficult to understand.

The running result of the below code is:

```
Mission Fibonacci1Async cost 9.4195388 seconds, value 75025
Mission Fibonacci2Async cost 0.2260129 seconds, value 75025
```

The only different is the 2rd function added a line **await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t1, t2 });**, make the performance increase 40 times.

Could anybody can explain to me?

```
    static Task<int> Fibonacci1Async(int n)
    {
        return Task.Run<int>(() => Fibonacci1(n));
    }

    static int Fibonacci1(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n == 1) return 1;
        else
        {
            var t1 = Fibonacci1Async(n - 1);
            var t2 = Fibonacci1Async(n - 2);
            return t1.Result + t2.Result;
        }
    }

    static Task<int> Fibonacci2Async(int n)
    {
        return Task.Run<int>(() => Fibonacci2(n));
    }

    static int Fibonacci2(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n == 1) return 1;
        else
        {
            var t1 = Fibonacci2Async(n - 1);
            var t2 = Fibonacci2Async(n - 2);

            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t1, t2 });
            return t1.Result + t2.Result;
        }
    }

    static void Benchmark(Func<int, Task<int>> func)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        var task = func(25);
        task.Wait();
        TimeSpan cost = DateTime.Now - time;
        Console.WriteLine("Mission {0} cost {1} seconds value {2}", func.Method.Name, cost.TotalSeconds, task.Result);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Benchmark(Fibonacci1Async);
        Benchmark(Fibonacci2Async);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answer has to do with [`Task.Wait` inlining](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx).

In the expression `t1.Result + t2.Result`, the `+` operator evaluates its arguments (serially) left-to-right. So it'll block on `t1` and then on `t2`.

I'm guessing that on your system, much of the time `t1` has already started but not `t2`. In this case, `Task.WaitAll` can "inline" `t2` into the current thread pool task instead of starting a new one, but `+` will block on `t1`.

This is just a guess; you should use a profiler to find out exactly what's going on.

I wasn't able to reproduce this on my system. I always see both versions being about the same, even with processor affinity applied to the process.

P.S. The naming convention `Async` doesn't really apply here. This code isn't using `async`/`await` - it's using the Task Parallel Library.

Comment: The naming convention has nothing to do with await/async. This is an implementation detail. It specifies that the caller receives a task and gets non-blocking behavior.

Comment: The postfix `Async` combined with the return type implies the method uses the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern. I suppose you could make a case that these `*Async` methods are TAP, but they're certainly not a *good* example of a TAP implementation.

Comment: FileStream.ReadAsync does not use await internally for example. It uses IO completion ports. Nothing wrong with it. The caller does not need to know.

Comment: `FileStream.ReadAsync` does not implement a `Task` wrapper around essentially synchronous code, either.